# Linear vs nonlinear seismic inversion

Tags: seismic, inversion

I am using the MATLAB script BLIMP (Ferguson and Margrave, 1995) to invert SH-wave data for shear-impedance. Is this inversion scheme a linear or non-linear process? There are certainly non-linear calculations occurring (i.e. integration and exponentiation), but I am unsure if that automatically qualifies it as non-linear.

For whatever answer you have, please provide some reference for me to track down.

Comment: It's linear. Integration is a linear filter and the exponentiation part is just a conditioning step in order to "linearize" the problem and then use simple linear inversion techniques. Sorry, don't have time to search for references.